# Can a Third-Party App Track my IP when I Use It?

Tags: 18.04, security

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed and I also have some apps on it, such as Microsoft Teams. Now, I was wondering: Can such apps, that are from "third parties", so to say, track my IP when I use it? Obviously, if I use their services on the websites, they can, but how is it if I have it as an app installed?

Obviously, I could now go through all the privacy policies of all the third-party apps that are installed, but doing this properly might take weeks..

Comment: Applications can indeed query the system to learn your current IP address...if they are running. One easy solution is to not have a lot of random applications running all the time (this will also save your battery). Another easy solution is to avoid installing applications that need to be always-on in the background. Yet another solution is to avoid installing shady applications that spy on you. The Ubuntu Repositories have a lot of great, safe software. And the Ubuntu Security Team would love to know if you discover spyware that is compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking of applications that are running, such as Microsoft Teams! Great to know. Could you please elaborate on the "Applications can indeed query the system to learn your current IP address...", or post a reference or anything alike?

Comment: I find it difficult to envision why an application like Microsoft Teams would be running...but not connected to the network. Nor why Teams would need to record your IP address. Nor why a LAN IP address (192.168.1.5 and such) would be useful to record. Remember that IP addresses are *supposed* to be public, like your telephone number or your postal address. Perhaps you should clarify your question: What are you really worried about?